# Map synchronization with double check locking

Tags: java, synchronization, double-checked-locking

I've read about [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java) and its drawbacks, but I'm asking if using a `synchronizedMap` can be considered safe.

Here is my code:

```
public class EntityUtils
{
    private static final Map<String, Map<String, String>> searchMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>());

    private static Map<String, String> getSearchablePathMap(String key)
    {
        Map<String, String> pathMap = searchMap.get(key);
        if(pathMap != null) return pathMap;

        synchronized(searchMap)
        {
            // double check locking (safe for synchronizedMap?)
            pathMap = searchMap.get(key);
            if(pathMap != null) return pathMap;

            pathMap = new HashMap<>();
            pathMap.put(..., ...);
            ...
            // heavy map population operations
            ...

            pathMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(pathMap);

            searchMap.put(key, pathMap);
        }

        return pathMap;
    }
}
```

Suggestions or improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's safe, but it doesn't have any advantages in this case.

Double-checked locking is used to avoid costly synchronization on the most frequent code path, but in your case `get()` is synchronized as well, therefore you actually have two synchronized blocks instead of one.

Comment: the second `get()` is inside synchronization block, but the first one is outside. The outside one could return a **corrupted** `Map` using a *non threadsafe* object, so `synchronizedMap` is *necessary*. My doubt is if it is also sufficient.

Comment: Of course, it's sufficient. The point is that the first `get()` doesn't give you any performance benefit, because it has a `synchronized` block inside (due to `synchronizedMap`).

Comment: you are right, it's safe but double check doesn't give any performance benefit. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) has a [putIfAbsent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,%20V)) method that might help.

There is a slight obstacle in your scenario in that if the key is absent then your code both creates and populates a new map. There is an overhead to using putIfAbsent on the "not absent" execution path if the value to be set in the absent case has a significant construction cost, but if the construction cost is cheap or can be amortised over many calls then this might be useful.

Using a method from the standard library is very likely to be safer than rolling your own unless you have particular expertise in Java concurrency.

Comment: absolutely correct, but this is the worst case for `putIfAbsent`, i edited my question accordingly.